# Test irreducibility of polynomial over finite field

Tags: field-theory

I am reading a text, where it says that $X^5-X-1$ is irreducible modulo 3. I am not sure how I can know that. Could someone help?

By the way, is there some practical trick to judge whether a polynomial irreducible over a finite field in general? Because when I calculate the galois group I find this information is very important, so I am very curious. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it the crude way. There are no roots, so without loss of generality we can look for a decomposition into a monic cubic times a monic quadratic. Then see what the coefficients should be. Somewhat painful, but not lengthy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ops, sure, thanks! But I am still curious about other finite fields.

Comment: There is theory that (sometimes) helps. But at this stage the best one can do is probably clever manipulation from basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**  $\:\!\color{#0a0}f\:\!$ has no roots $\in\Bbb F_3$  so no linear factors. If it splits it has an irreducible $\rm\color{#90f}{quadratic}$ factor $\color{#90f}g.\,$ In  $\,\Bbb F_9\! = \Bbb F_3[x]/\color{#90f}g\!:\: $ $\underbrace{x^8\! = 1}_{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\large \Rightarrow\,\ \color{#c00}{{x^4}\ =\ \pm1}}\,$ so $\,0\! =\underbrace{\color{#c00}{x^4}\color{0a0a}x\!-\!x\!-\!1}_{\large \color{#0a0}{\deg f\ \le\ 1}}\, $ so $\,\color{#90f}g\mid\color{#0a0} f\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_3[x],\,$ contra $\,\color{#90f}{\deg g \!=\! 2},\,\color{#0a0}{\deg f\!\le\! 1}$.

**Remark** $ $ We used $ f^{\large \color{#c00}8}\! = 1\,$ for $\,0\!\neq \!f\in \Bbb F_9,\,$ an analogue of Fermat's little Theorem, which is true by $\,\Bbb  F_9$ has multiplicative group $\,\Bbb F_9^*$ of size $\,\color{#c00}8 = 9\color{#0a0}{-1}\,$ ($\rm non\color{#0a0}{zero}$ elements are invertible in a field), so [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) $\Rightarrow f^{\large \color{#c00}8}\! = 1\,$ for all $\,f\!\neq\! 0.$

Above is essentially a special case of a general  [polynomial irreducibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853656/242) over finite fields - which is an an *efficient* analog of the impractical [Pocklington-Lehmer integer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214866/242) for a simpler example done this way: $\,x^5+x^3 - 1\pmod{\!2}\ \ $